# MySQL floating point numbers being unexpectedly rounded

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm not sure whether it's MySQL cutting off the number, or some hidden config in Codeigniter, which is what I'm using.

The field in question is:

```
`total` float(12,4) unsigned NOT NULL
```

This is the insert code of the data:

```
$data = array(
    // ...
    'total' => $datos['total'], // value is 577.82999999999
);
$res = $this->db->insert($this->tabla, $data); // Codeigniter DB insertion method
```

It's storing this value:

**577.8300**

Shouldn't it be:

**577.8299**  ??

Comment: no, because you're storing in a `,4` float field. `8300` is CLOSER to .82999999 and then 8299 is. 0.0001 v.s. 0.0009 difference.

Comment: It's MySQL that is "cutting off the number" [sic]. The rounding operation isn't "unexpected". The behavior you observe conforms to the specification, documented in the MySQL Reference Manual: [**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html).

Comment: I see. So everything's fine! Thank you!

Comment: Your field should more likely be DECIMAL rather than FLOAT type.

Comment: @Niagaradad I'll take that into account, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float(12,4)` means that you'll store `total` value with 12 digits whereas 4 of them will be destinated to store the decimal part.

That's why `577.82999999999` becomes `577.8300`. Furthermore, it won't be stored as `577.8299` because every number limited must be rounded instead of just ignoring the rest of digits.

In other words imagine you have that same number but want to store it with only 2 digits for decimal part. If you just ignore the other digits (without making rounding) you'll end up with `577.82`. However our original number was closer to `577.83` and with that we'd lose precision.

**Going Further: How rounding works**

The following algorithm shows how rounding works:

```
Get first digit after limit
if it is equal to or greater than 5
  add 1 to digit at limit
end
```

Thus `577.82999999999` will become `577.8300` because 1 is added to the 4th digit of decimal part. That digi is `9` which leads to a propagation of 1's and will end up in `577.8300`.

Comment: I knew 4 digits out of a total of 12 where designated for the decimal part, and I also supposed MySQL would round decimals. The thing is that I didn't realize that 577.8300 is more accurate than 577.8299 to represent 577.82999999999 (fool me). That's why I thought, and I was wrong, it was rounding to 2 decimals instead of four.

Comment: @user3514092 based on your doubts I updated my answer. I hope you can now understand why the final result is 577.8300 instead of 577.8299. Please choose my answer if you got it :D